# Windows 11 - multiple monitors - weird zoom-out zoom-in animation of screens

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11, animation

Any time any or all displays in my multi monitor set up is turned on (can be by turning one on with a hardware button, or when screens are waken up, or when waking up computer from sleep state) this weird zoom-out-zoom-in happens on all screens.

The computer is unusable during this animation and although it take 1-2 seconds it is super annoying.

Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> to open the start menu then type *"Animation"* then select *Animation effects*. Alternatively in Settings go to *Accessibility > Visual effects*

In the Visual effects screen **turn *Animation effects* off**

[image: Animation effects settings]

[How to disable visual effects to speed up Windows 11](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-visual-effects-speed-windows-11)

Comment: This works and removes the effect. But the issue is the delay is still present. :(